# S3 lifecycle - deleting files which are x months old

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket in which i have some zip files created from the year 2016 till the year 2017, i wanted to apply a life cycle rule for deleting files which are 6 months older than the current date, i did that, in theory that bucket should have no files  since all of them are at least 1 year old? but all the files remain intact.
please find the image below for life cycle settings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0sUl.jpg
what am i missing here

Comment: Is there a reason why you have not selected "current version" in your lifecycle policy settings?

Comment: is there any difference in that?

Comment: There is a very significant difference in that.  The "current version" of an object is the most recently uploaded version of every object visible in the bucket.

Comment: actually with the setting i have, the S3 bucket is cleared as expected after 24 hours... wow